# Accessing 2nd nested div's table element's height property

Tags: jquery, html

I have posted complete body of my web page. I need to access elements in the second div of parent div with id productgrid2. This would be the second div with height 219.3999 in the code below. Specifically I need the height of the table of this second div. This would be the table with class k-selectable. Problem is those elements are dynamically generated and I need to access them via jQuery. Looked around but nothing matched my unique situation. Can someone help with this?

```
<div id="productgrid2" style="border: 1px solid rgb(54, 57, 64); box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 7px 7px 5px; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 250px;" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget">
        <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 14px;">
            <div class="k-grid-header-wrap" data-role="resizable">
                <table role="grid">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width:170px">
                        <col style="width:135px">
                        <col style="width:120px">
                        <col style="width:75px">
                        <col style="width:55px">
                        <col style="width:60px">
                        <col style="width:190px">
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead role="rowgroup">
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="rfi_name" data-title="RFI/Click2Connect" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">RFI/Click2Connect</a></th>
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="SelectedOptions" data-title="Fulfillment" class="k-header k-with-icon k-filterable" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-grid-filter" href="#" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-filter" data-original-title="" title=""></span></a><a class="k-link" href="#">Fulfillment</a></th>
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="InteractiveID" data-title="Interactive ID" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Interactive ID</a></th>
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="ISCI" data-title="ISCI" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">ISCI</a></th>
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="IsAddressable" data-title="Addressable" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Addressable</a></th>
                            <th role="columnheader" data-field="Status" data-title="Status" class="k-header" data-role="columnsorter"><a class="k-link" href="#">Status</a></th>
                            <th class="k-header">View, Duplicate or Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="k-grid-content" style="height: 219.399999976158px;">
            <table role="grid" data-role="selectable" class="k-selectable" style="height: auto;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width:170px">
                    <col style="width:135px">
                    <col style="width:120px">
                    <col style="width:75px">
                    <col style="width:55px">
                    <col style="width:60px">
                    <col style="width:190px">
                </colgroup>
                <tbody role="rowgroup">
                    <tr data-uid="c2f68916-0f9e-4a54-a5a2-c95f2de2afe7" role="row">
                        <td role="gridcell">Hunhhh?</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">Mail</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">000000ET00025868</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">654654</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">Yes</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">Draft</td>
                        <td role="gridcell"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Edit" href="#"><span class=" k-icon k-i-search ob-icon-only"></span></a><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Duplicate" href="#"><span class=" k-icon k-i-restore ob-icon-only"></span></a><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Delete" href="#"><span class=" k-icon k-i-close ob-icon-only"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="5749733a-f164-4557-b6b1-d45c7bb74d60" role="row">
                        <td role="gridcell">Test RFI 1</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">Mail</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">000000ET00025867</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">232654</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">No</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">Draft</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Edit" href="#">
                                <span class=" k-icon k-i-search ob-icon-only"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Duplicate" href="#">
                                <span class=" k-icon k-i-restore ob-icon-only"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Delete" href="#">
                                <span class=" k-icon k-i-close ob-icon-only"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Starting from where, which element, and in response to what event?

Comment: So starting from here I need to access the table element. The one at the end. The one with class="k-selectable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you cannot define/retrieve fractions of pixels, I think what you want is to use the nth-child selector:

```
$("#productgrid2 div:nth-child(2)").height()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8979zm7/)

Comment: I actually need the div's table. So let me try something like div:nth-child(2) table

Comment: For some reaosn adding table doesn't work in my code. :(

Comment: Found the reason. I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and accordion. Due to the div being hidden by accordion the table width was not being computed. Once I opened the accordion section I started getting the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you can't access the height because the element doesn't exist yet when you run the function? If so, you could try this. It is a jQuery function that waits until an element exists and then runs whatever functions you would like. I got it from some other SO question quite sometime ago, but I don't remember where or I would give reference to the question.

```
$.fn.waitUntilExists = function(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, isChild) {
  var $elements, $this, found;
  found = "found";
  $this = $(this.selector);
  $elements = $this.not(function() {
    return $(this).data(found);
  }).each(handler).data(found, true);
  if (!isChild) {
    (window.waitUntilExists_Intervals = window.waitUntilExists_Intervals || {})[this.selector] = window.setInterval(function() {
      $this.waitUntilExists(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, true);
    }, 500);
  } else {
    if (shouldRunHandlerOnce && $elements.length) {
      window.clearInterval(window.waitUntilExists_Intervals[this.selector]);
    }
  }
  return $this;
};
```

You can just use it like this:

```
$(selector).waitUntilExists(functionToRunOnSelector);
```

Comment: Not what I needed. But might be helpful to others. Thanks